# Segmentation Fault in template operator overload

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I am currently trying to get to grips with templates and operator overloading in C++. I've written a class which is basically a wrapper of a vector. I am trying to add operator overloading to the template class so I can iterate over the list but I keep receiving a segmentation fault with the overloaded operator.

Here is the template code.

```
template <class T> class List {
private:
    std::list<T *> *objects;
    int count;
    uint currentIndex;
    typename std::list<T*>::iterator item_iter;

public:
    T *currentItem;
    T *get(int idx);
    void add(T *obj);
    void start();
    bool empty();
    void next();
    List<T>& operator++();

    List() {
        this->currentItem = NULL;
        this->currentIndex = 0;
        this->count = 0;
        this->objects = new std::list<T *>;
    }

    ~List() {
        delete this->objects;
    }
};

template <class T>
void List<T>::add(T *obj) {
    this->objects->push_back(obj);
}

template <class T>
T *List<T>::get(int idx) {
    if (idx < this->objects->size()) {
      typename std::list<T*>::iterator it = this->objects->begin();
      std::advance(it, idx);
      return *it;
    } else {
      return NULL;
    }
}

template <class T>
void List<T>::start() {
    this->currentIndex = 0;
    if (this->objects->size() > 0) {
      this->item_iter = this->objects->begin();
      this->currentItem = *(this->item_iter);
    } else {
      this->currentItem = NULL;
    }
}

template <class T>
void List<T>::next() {
     if (!this->empty() && (this->currentIndex == 0) && (this->currentItem == NULL)) {
      this->start();
    } else if (this->currentIndex < this->objects->size() - 1) {
      this->currentIndex++;
      std::advance(item_iter, 1);
      this->currentItem = *item_iter;
    } else {
      this->currentItem = NULL;
    }
}

template <class T>
bool List<T>::empty() {
    return !this->objects->size();
}

template <class T>
List<T>& List<T>::operator++() {
    // Note: We don't get this far
    this->next();
    return *this;
}
```

The following code works.

```
List<Item> *items = new List<Item>();
items->addItem(new Item(20));

for(items->start(); items->currentItem != NULL; items->next()) {
    // Can work with items->currentItem;
}
```

The following code causes the segmentation fault.

```
List<Item> *items = new List<Item>();
items->addItem(new Item(20));

for(items->start(); items->currentItem != NULL; items++) {
    // Segmentation fault occurs before we get inside
}
```

Comment: In `for(items->start(); items->currentItem != NULL; items++)` the variable `items` is a pointer, so `items++` increments the pointer. It isn't pointing to a valid instance anymore. You might have meant `(*iter)++`?

Comment: Why are you going overboard with using `new`?  C++ is not Java.  You have memory leaks galore.

Comment: `std::list<T *> *objects;` Don't do that. Like, ever. You don't need pointers here **at all**. `T *currentItem;` Don't. `void start();` Don't. `void next();` Don't. This kind of interface is **extremely** bad. Don't do this even for learning.

Comment: `{List<int> list1; List<int> list2 = list1;}` -- If you want more holes, this two line program has a double deletion error.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux you were correct, I needed (*items)++ and the operator overload needed to take in an int.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks, I'll clean it up now!

Comment: @n.m. I know this type of interface is bad, this is a project for college so we just needed to add a template... I wouldn't use this in reality..

Comment: A template is OK, `start` and `end` and `current` are not. What else is not OK? Not knowing the *rule of three*.

Comment: @n.m. yeah, it's pretty tough to know about a rule that you haven't heard of before. I'll read up on it, thanks.

Comment: Either you shouldn't use pointers in this assignment, or your course should have explained the rule of three. If it didn't up to this point it's pretty bad.

Comment: The project is to basically apply as many C++ features into the application.. i.e. templates, operator overloading, virtual functions, pure virtual functions, coercion, memory allocation, etc.. And no, we haven't been taught the Rule of 3 in the module... We're shown what it can do, but not how to use it properly...

Comment: @Dobz -- Not using the rule of 3 is the reason that 2 line program I posted earlier [crashes, as seen here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e25e951fae18719).  It is not a matter of 'how to use it properly, it is a requirement if objects are copied, and the objects contains things such as members that are pointers to dynamically allocated memory.  Ask your teacher why that simple program crashes, and if they can't answer, you're in trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@FrançoisAndrieux was correct.

I needed to dereference the items pointer.

```
for(items.start(); items.currentItem != NULL; ++items) {
    // Can now use current item
}
```

I also changed the return type.

```
template <class T>
List<T> List<T>::operator++() {
    this->next();
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: `operator++(int)` and `operator++()` are distinct operators. `operator++()` is the pre-increment operator (`++i`) while `operator++(int)` is the post-increment operator (`i++`). The post-increment operator should return `List<T>` not `List<T>&`. You could use `++(*items)` instead if you wanted to use `operator++()`. [Link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thank you, I'll change it.